# NodeJS Countdown

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm calling Submit button and adding the checked values for each click.
I want to add a countdown and say:
Every 60 seconds only 1 click of the user will be counted. Else show alert.

Here is my code:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

    const choice = document.querySelector('input[name=os]:checked').value;
    const data = {os:choice}

    fetch('localhost:3000/poll', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
    // alert("Danke für die Abstimmung")

.catch(err => console.log(err));
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **flag** to check the time difference. Once the user clicks on **submit** button, you can **store** the time in a variable. If the user clicked on the submit button again, check the **difference between the current time and last submit time** (which you store in a variable). If the time difference is less than 60 seconds, show the alert message otherwise do the post request.

```
var submissionTime = undefined;

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  var flag = true;

  if(submissionTime) {
    var milliseconds = new Date().getTime() - submissionTime.getTime();
    var seconds = Math.abs(milliseconds / 1000);
    if(seconds < 61) {
      flag = false;
      // show the alert
    }
  }
  
  if(flag) {
    submissionTime = new Date();
    const choice = document.querySelector('input[name=os]:checked').value;
    const data = {os:choice}

    fetch('localhost:3000/poll', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    // alert("Danke für die Abstimmung")
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

});
```